# When trying to package a Python project it can't find Sqlite3 database after pip install

Tags: python, pypi

Is it possible to package a Python project with an Sqlite3 database?

Each time I try to package it all up the script can't find the database file. It fails with this error `sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`

This is what I have currently. Can anyone spot something I'm missing or doing wrong?

**file structure**

```
setup.cfg  
setup.py  
invoicing/  
 |__ __init__.py  
 |__ invoicing.py  
 |__ sqlite3/  
   |__ invoicing_live.db  
 |__ constants  
   |__ constants.py
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

readme = open('README.md', 'r')
README_TEXT = readme.read()
readme.close()

setup(
    name='project',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='Blah blah',
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'project=project.__main__:main',
        ],
    },
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['contrib', 'docs', 'tests*']),
    package_data={'project': 'sqlite3/*.db'},
    python_requires='>=3.5',
)
```

**constants.py**

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename

DB_PATH = resource_filename('project', '/sqlite3')
DB = DB_PATH + '/project_live.db'
```

Comment: Have you tried with `package_data={'project': 'invoicing/sqlite3/*.db'},` or `DB_PATH = resource_filename('project', 'invoicing/sqlite3')` ?

Comment: I have it working now, I didn't change anything I just deleted the build and dist folders and uninstalled the `.whl` package. I think it may have been reusing the build files or something.